# At application startup change all time calls to be from same time but change the year to 1991

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is it possible each time the application starts it can run at a time in the past for demo purposes. i.e all time calls need to return a time in the past!
Run a demo that starts on 1991, I do not want to change the system time. So each time the app starts it sets its time to 1991.

In the project I have a lot of calls of `System.currentTimeMillis()` but I don't want for every line of code where `currentTimeMillis` is used to subtract it there I would like maybe overriding `System.currentTimeMillis()` and internally subtracting the amount of years between now and 1991 and then question is: "Is it possible?".

Comment: You should be using `java.time.Clock`; that's the reason it exists.

Comment: .. if only there was a way to go back to 1991 ...